# Determine if Reynolds Number is large or small in classical mechanics.

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics

In classical Mechanics, there is a reference to the Reynolds Number ( Re=ρvd/η (ρ density, v velocity, d diameter and η the viscosity of fluid)) that relates the ratio $$ f_{\text{quadratic}}/ f_{\text{linear}}$$

When the Reynolds number is large, the quadratic term is important, and when small, the linear term is important. How will I know if the Reynolds Number is large or small in determining when to use the quadratic or linear terms for air resistance in the equation like:

$$f(v) = bv + c^2v = f_{\text{linear}} + f_{\text{quadratic}}$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the Reynolds Number well defined for a given system?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/272738/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have two boundary conditions from which to evaluate the constants "b" and "c", or the constants "b" and "c" are already known, you don't need to worry about Reynold's number.  Use the equation as stated.  At low velocities, the linear term will dominate the equation, at intermediate velocities, each term will contribute to the resistance force approximately "equally", and at high velocities, the quadratic term will dominate.